# How does mysqlimport work internally?

Tags: mysql, mysqlimport

As MySQL doc says `LOAD DATA INFILE` is 20x times faster than bulk insert(`INSERT VALUES`), I am tring to replace `INSERT VALUES` with `LOAD DATA INFILE` in my application.

When I try `LOAD DATA INFILE` with ADO.NET, it ends in an error. It seems there is no way to load a file from local machine where MySQL is not running.

But that is not a problem for mysqlimport, the doc also says that.

> You can also load data files by using the mysqlimport utility; it
>   operates by sending a LOAD DATA INFILE statement to the server. The
>   --local option causes mysqlimport to read data files from the client host.

I am curious about what the protocol is used by mysqlimport when it imports data into MySQL on a remote machine.

Is it parsing the data file and construct SQL like `INSERT VALUES`? 
or it has a special protocol to send the data file directly to MySQL?

Comment: If you can understand c/c++ you can check it yourself the source code of mysql and tools for mysql are open source

Comment: No special protocol just a C mysql_query function the -local option adds LOCAL to the LOAD DATA INFILE